# Visual Studio: Error when removing a project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know what extension causes this whenever you remove a project from a solution in Visual Studio 2010?

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

### Visual Studio has encountered an unexpected error.

### OK

Comment: Try disabling your extensions.

Comment: Start a second copy of VS, attach its debugger to the first one, and see what exception gets thrown.

Comment: Do you have a class file open when you try to remove the project?  It happens to me if I have a class file open in the editor and try to remove the project it belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

I've been having this problem for a while.

I have installed four extensions from the Online Gallery:

- I Hate #Regions v1.2.6
- Productivity Power Tools v10.0.20626.18
- Visual Studio Background Customizer v1.0
- Visual Studio Color Theme Editor v1.3

For me, the offending extension is Productivity Power Tools.

I have just confirmed this by turning off all of my extensions, then enabling one (and only one) at a time, removing a project from a solution, and then attempting to save the solution.

With Productivity Power Tools as the only enabled extension, I received the "Visual Studio has encountered an unexpected error" message.

Hope this helps.